# How to set the default value of a column in sqlalchemy to the value of a column from a relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am setting up a Sqlalchemy mapper for a sqlite database. My User class has a non-nullable relationship with my Team class. The code I already have is as follows:

```
class Team(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'teams'

    team_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    # Using Integer as holder for boolean
    is_local = Column(Integer, default=0)

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    user_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    team_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Team.team_id), default=1, nullable=False)
    team = relationship('Team')
    is_local = Column(Integer, default=0)
```

I would like to establish that the value of `User.is_local` is by default the value of `Team.is_local` for the User's linked team. 
*However*, after the creation of the User, I would still like the ability to modify the user's `is_local` value without changing the values of the team or any other user on the team.

So if I were to execute

```
faraway = Team(is_local=1)
session.add(faraway)
session.commit()

u = User(team=faraway)
session.add(u)
session.commit()

print(bool(u.is_local))
```

The result should be `True`

So far, I have tried context-sensitive default functions as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/a/36579924, but I have not been able to find the syntax allowing me to reference `Team.is_local`

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you could try using a sql expression as the default to select the value from the `team` table on insert, see: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#client-invoked-sql-expressions; or perhaps use an event listener to hook into an event such as `before_flush` to add the state to the instances on their way in to the DB. See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.before_flush. Apologies for not writing a formal answer as I’m on my phone, but thought I’d share a couple of ideas that might help to get you moving.

Comment: @SuperShoot the first suggestion seems to work. I was stumped for a hot second by the typo (single `=` instead of `==`) in the example

Answer (score 1):

The first suggestion from SuperShoot, using a [sql expression as the default](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#client-invoked-sql-expressions) appears to work. Specifically,

```
    is_local = Column(Integer, default=select([Team.is_local]).where(Team.team_id==team_id))
```

gives me the logic I require.