# Compute the value of a column based on other columns in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy as an ORM in a Python codebase to be able to connect with a MySQL db. I want to be able to automatically calculate and insert a value in a column based on the values in other columns of the same row.

This is what my class looks like:

```py
class SentNotification(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sent_notification'

    campaign = Column(VARCHAR(34), nullable=False)
    alert_type = Column(VARCHAR(34), nullable=False)
    identifier = Column(VARCHAR(34), nullable=False)
    message_params = Column(JSON, nullable=True)
    send_time = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    nonce = Column(VARCHAR(32), nullable=False, primary_key=True)
```

The `nonce` column is supposed to be an md5 hash (or any other custom function) of `campaign`, `alert_type`, `identifier` and `message_params` (json dump).

I can obviously calculate this separately and call `SentNotification` with the `nonce` but it would be much more cleaner if I could only pass in the first 5 values and my class would automatically take care of the calculation and insertion of the `nonce`.

Note: I do not want to use hybrid property since that calculates the value and I want to actually persist the `nonce` in the database.

Comment: Have a look at [`Context Sensitive Default Functions`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions), should be what you are looking for. Basically, you can define a function that computes a default value for a column with access to the other values being inserted at the time.

Comment: This is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579355/sqlalchemy-set-default-value-of-one-column-to-that-of-another-column

Comment: In addition I believe that MySQL has computed/generated columns, both materialized and not. Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

It's about [context-sensitive default functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/defaults.html#context-sensitive-default-functions). you can use it as:

```
def mydefault(context):
    params = context.get_current_parameters()
    return hash(params['campaign'],params['alert_type'],params['identifier'], params['message_params'])

class SentNotification(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sent_notification'

    campaign = Column(VARCHAR(34), nullable=False)
    alert_type = Column(VARCHAR(34), nullable=False)
    identifier = Column(VARCHAR(34), nullable=False)
    message_params = Column(JSON, nullable=True)
    send_time = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    nonce = Column(VARCHAR(32), nullable=False, primary_key=True, default=mydefault)
```