# SQLAlchemy set default value of column depending on ID

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I already know that for general cases: this question is sufficient: [SQLAlchemy set default value of one column to that of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579355/sqlalchemy-set-default-value-of-one-column-to-that-of-another-column)

But when my column depends on the Id column it doesn't work because id is auto generated.

For eg: Using the same example as the other question

```
class Substance(Base):
    __tablename__ = "substances"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    subtance_hash = Column(String, unique=True, default=hashgen)

def hashgen(context):
    uid = context.get_current_parameters()['id'] + 100
    name = context.get_current_parameters()['name']
    code = context.get_current_parameters()['code']
    return some_hash_function(uid, name, code)

def some_hash_function(uid, name, code):
    # this is a stupid example for completeness
    return str(uid) + str(name) + str(code)
```

The problem here is that uid is None because it will be auto generated while committing the query I think?

So it throws an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.KeyError) 'id'
```

Is it even possible to do this? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

You can flush your session to set the id before the commit.  You can then calculate your hash.  You can also use the event system is SQLAlchemy to listen for `after_flush` events and calculate the hash there.  For example:

```py
class Substance(Base):
    __tablename__ = "substances"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    subtance_hash = Column(String, unique=True)


@event.listens_for(sessionOrSessionFactory, 'after_flush')
def hashgen(session, flush_context):
    for obj in session:
        if isinstance(obj, Substance):
            obj.substance_hash = some_hash_function(obj)


def some_hash_function(obj):
    # this is a stupid example for completeness
    return str(obj.id + 100) + str(obj.name) + str(obj.code)
```

Another method is to make the hash hybrid_property https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html

I haven't played around with hybrid properties much so I will leave it for someone else to contribute an answer for that.