# How to automatically calculate a field in a SQLalchemy table in python?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table with the fields `create_date` and `due_date`. I want `due_date` to always be 90 days after the `create_date`. I want the `due_date` field to be automatically generated without inserting into that column. From what I have looked up it seems like `column_property` may be what I need.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    created_date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    due_date = column_property(created_date + timedelta(days=90))
```

This segment of code runs without an error. The table gets created however the due_date column does not get created.

Comment: and? what error/behavior are you getting when you do use `column_property`?

Comment: This segment of code runs without an error. The table gets created however the due_date column does not get created.

Comment: It sounds like [column_property](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapping_columns.html#sqlalchemy.orm.column_property) doesn't create a column table-side, just a representation of one ORM-side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Column` with `default`, that way, SQLAlchemy will set `due_date` if it's ever null when the object is first created:

```py
def default_due_date(context):
    return context.get_current_parameters()['created_date'] + timedelta(days=90)

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = "my_table"
    created_date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    due_date = Column(DateTime, default=default_due_date)
```

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36579924/5015356) on how to base the default on the value of another field.

Comment: Current error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_current_parameters'`. `get_current_parameters` is sqlalchemy version 1.2 which is supported by python 2.7+. I am using python 3.8.3, not sure why I would be receiving this.

Comment: `context` is a string in your code. Do you know its value? Can you print it inside `default_due_date`?