# Set default value of one column to another column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-triggers

Is it possible in PostgreSQL to have a column's default value be equal to another column? This seems to be possible in [SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36579355/sqlalchemy-set-default-value-of-one-column-to-that-of-another-column) and possibly other database frameworks, but ideally this would be done in pure SQL.

For example,

```sql
-- given
create table my_example(
    column_a int primary key,
    column_b int default column_a
);

-- when
insert into my_example (column_a) values (42);

-- then this should return 42
select column_b from my_example where column_a=42;
```

When I try this myself, I the `create table` statement throws this error:

> `[0A000] ERROR: cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression`

This indicates to me that this is not possible to do, but I'm wondering if there is there some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Why? Just use COALESCE

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell this is only achievable using triggers. The column has to be created without using the `default` keyword, and then you have to trigger an update on each inserted row.

```sql
create table my_example(
    column_a int primary key,
    column_b int
);

create or replace function column_b_default()
returns trigger as $$
begin
    if new.column_b is null then
        new.column_b := new.column_a;
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger column_b_default_trigger
before insert on my_example
for each row
    execute procedure column_b_default();
```

Something else I tried, but is not really a solution to this in general, is to use `generated always`. This comes with a drawback that you cannot insert values directly into `column_b` so I can't consider this a drop-in replacement for the `default` keyword. But, it's much less verbose than creating a trigger so it might be useful in some cases.

```sql
create table my_example(
    column_a int primary key,
    column_b int generated always as (column_a) stored
);
```